# Main возвращает неверное значение

Tags: c#, main

Есть программа, которая по выполнению должна вернуть 0 или 1 в случае успеха/отказа. Операции можно прервать сочетанием клавиш. При прерывании в глобальную переменную stopState должно падать значение true, но оно остаётся false, соответственно Main отвечает неверно. Помогите разобраться

Вот код:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleThreadTest
{
    class Program
    {
        // основной поток
        static void MainThread(string typeJob,string fileInput, string fileOut)
        {
            Zip zip = new Zip();
            zip.Action(typeJob, fileInput, fileOut);

        }
        // фоновый поток
        static void listenKey(Thread th)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
            Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;
            while (true)
            {
                cki = Console.ReadKey();
                if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0 && cki.Key == ConsoleKey.C)
                {
                    stopState = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("StopState = {0}", stopState);
                    Console.WriteLine("Программа остановлена вручную");
                    Console.WriteLine("Целевой файл удалён");
                    th.Abort();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ActionJob(string typeJob, string fileInput, string fileOut)
        {
            if (FileCheck.CheckPath(fileInput, fileOut))
            {
                if (FileCheck.FileExistCheck(fileInput, fileOut))
                {
                    Thread actionThread = new Thread(() => MainThread(typeJob, fileInput, fileOut));
                    Thread listenKeyThread = new Thread(() => listenKey(actionThread));
                    listenKeyThread.IsBackground = true;
                    actionThread.Start();
                    listenKeyThread.Start();                    
                }                    
            }           
        }


        public static bool stopState = false;


        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            //stopState = false;            
            if (args.Length == 3)
            {
                ActionJob(args[0], args[1], args[2]);                 
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Парметры запуска заданы неверно");
            }
            if ((!File.Exists(args[2]) && (stopState == false)))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else return 1;

        }
    }
}
```

FileCheck.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleThreadTest
{
    class FileCheck
    {
        public static bool CheckPath(string fileInput, string fileOut)
        {
            // паттерн для проверки второго и третьего параметров
            string pattern = @"([a-zA-Z]:(\/|\\))((\w+(\/|\\))*(\w+(.\w+)?))";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(fileInput, pattern))
            {
                if (Regex.IsMatch(fileOut, pattern))
                {
                    return (true);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("третий параметр не является путём к файлу");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("второй параметр не является путём к файлу");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static bool FileExistCheck(string fileInput, string fileOut)
        {
            if (File.Exists(fileInput))
            {
                if (!File.Exists(fileOut))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Имя целевого файла уже используется");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Указанного файла не существует");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Zip.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleThreadTest
{
    class Zip
    {
        public void Action(string typeJob, string fileInput, string fileOut)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ctrl + c - для отмены...");
            if (FileCheck.FileExistCheck(fileInput,fileOut))
            {

                using (FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(fileInput, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (FileStream targetStream = File.Create(fileOut))
                    {
                        switch (typeJob)
                        {
                            case "compress":
                                Console.WriteLine("Упаковка файла: {0} в архив {1}", fileInput, fileOut);
                                using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(targetStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        sourceStream.CopyTo(compressionStream);
                                        break;

                                    }
                                    catch (ThreadAbortException)
                                    {
                                        if (sourceStream != null && compressionStream != null && targetStream != null)
                                        {
                                            sourceStream.Close();
                                            compressionStream.Close();
                                            targetStream.Close();
                                        }
                                        File.Delete(fileOut);
                                        break;

                                    }
                                }
                            case "decompress":
                                Console.WriteLine("Распаковка архива: {0} в файл {1}", fileInput, fileOut);
                                using (System.IO.Compression.GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(sourceStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        decompressionStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    catch (ThreadAbortException)
                                    {
                                        if (sourceStream != null && decompressionStream != null && targetStream != null)
                                        {
                                            sourceStream.Close();
                                            decompressionStream.Close();
                                            targetStream.Close();
                                        }
                                        File.Delete(fileOut);
                                        break;

                                    }
                                    catch (InvalidDataException)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Возможно путь к архиву указывает на файл иного типа");
                                        File.Delete(fileOut);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Первый аргумент указан неверно");
                                Console.WriteLine("Следует выбрать compress или decompress");
                                File.Delete(fileOut);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Сверился с ответом: Если добавить listenKey(Join), то программа не завершится, пока этот самый джойн не произойдёт, но он не обязательно должен происходить.

При срабатывании Ctrl+c stopState всё-равно считает false, добавил в listenKey при срабатывании stopState = true; однако в итоге программа возвращает всё тот же 0;

Обновил код на актуальный

Comment: _stopState = false_ - это присваивание, всегда возвращается `false`, следовательно выражение в if `(smth) && (false)` всегда будет ложно

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Если код актуальный, то где `.Join()`? Найди строку с `listenKeyThread.Start();` и затем ниже (после `.Start()`) добавь `listenKeyThread.Join();`

Comment: Там не нужен listenKey.Join, я в итоге поменял публичную булевую переменную на публичную переменную класса, и использовал её как триггер, всё заработало на ура. И да, дождаться окончания работы основной функции перед проверкой мне помог таки actionThread.join()

Answer (score 7):

Наверное, вы хотели использовать оператор `==` но получилось присваивание:

```
(stopState = false)
```

Так же, вы запускаете поток `listenKeyThread.Start()` и не дожидаетесь его остановки, а уже проверяете жив ли он или нет (он жив и крутит цикл). Если нужно дождаться выполнения потока, то вызовите следующей строкой `listenKeyThread.Join()` тогда всё заработает так, как вы ожидаете.

---

Конечно же, хочется ещё отметить, что для решения вашей задачи вам совершенно ненужен поток `listenKeyThread`. Что сейчас происходит? Запускается поток `listenKeyThread` и в тоже время основной поток `Main` ждет завершения этого потока и ничего полезного не делает. В вашем случае, логично было бы перенести код этого потока в `Main`, а `listenKeyThread` забыть как страшный сон.

Comment: Вы запускаете поток `listenKeyThread.Start()` и не дожидаетесь его остановки, а уже проверяете жив ли он или нет (он жив и крутит цикл). Если нужно дождаться выполнения потока, то вызовите следующей строкой `listenKeyThread.Join()` тогда всё заработает так, как вы ожидаете.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, перенеси свой комментарий в ответ